# List partitioning implemented recursively

Tags: haskell

I am a Haskell beginner and I have been experimenting with recursive functions.

I am working on a function:

```
 separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
```

that takes in a list and outputs all of the partitions of that list.

For example 123 becomes:

```
1|2|3
12|3
1|23
13|2
132
```

I have only been able to implement a recursive function that creates the `1|2|3` variant:

```
separate' :: [a] -> [[a]]
separate' (r:rs) = [r]:separate' xs

>separate [1,2,3]
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

I am stuck with trying to create the other variants with recursion.

Comment: Why do you include `132` but not `123` or `321`? I would take "partition" to mean that the output should not be re-arranged, i.e. `concat (concat (seperate x)) == x`, so `123` should be included but not `132` or `321`.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of this function as choosing, for each place in between two list elements, whether to include a split there. So for starters, there should be 2<sup>n-1</sup> partitions for an n-element list: you can use that as a quick sanity check on a possible solution.

One good way to model non-determinism is with the list monad (or equivalently with list comprehensions), so let's do it that way.

First, let's write the type and a base case:

```
separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
separate [] = [[]]
```

There is a single way to separate an empty list: the empty list itself, with no possibility of splits. Easy enough.

Now, given we have one element and a list of remaining elements, one thing we'll need for sure is a list of all the ways to split the remaining elements:

```
separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
separate [] = [[]]
separate (x:xs) = let recur = separate xs
                  in undefined -- TODO
```

Here's where the interesting stuff starts. As I said, you can view this as choosing, for each item, whether to put a split after it. Two choices means concatenating together two lists, so let's do that:

```
separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
separate [] = [[]]
separate (x:xs) = let recur = separate xs
                      split = undefined -- TODO
                      noSplit = undefined -- TODO
                  in split ++ noSplit
```

Now, how do we introduce a split after the item `x`? We do it by, for each partition in `recur`, adding `[x]` to the front of it as a new partition:

```
separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
separate [] = [[]]
separate (x:xs) = let recur = separate xs
                      split = do
                        partition <- recur
                        return $ [x] : partition
                      noSplit = undefined -- TODO
                  in split ++ noSplit
```

What about not splitting? Pretty similar! For each partition in `recur`, we add `x` to the front of the first sub-partition:

```
separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
separate [] = [[]]
separate (x:xs) = let recur = separate xs
                      split = do
                        partition <- recur
                        return $ [x] : partition
                      noSplit = do
                        (y:ys) <- recur
                        return $ (x:y):ys
                  in split ++ noSplit
```

And with that, we're done:

```
*Temp> separate "123"
[["1","2","3"],["1","23"],["12","3"],["123"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, as a beginner it really helps. I do have two questions though. After noSplit where does the "ys" come from? Also, from the Wikipedia page I was using to reference the definition of a partitioned list it also has [["13","2"]] listed as a possible outcome of "123". With this in mind how much more implementation would be needed to satisfy this condition?

Comment: What wikipedia page is this? It's hard to envision a problem statement that includes [13,2] but not, say, [3,12], so I can't say how you would make your desired change in a meaningful way. As for `ys`: each item in `recur` is a list of lists, so when we bind `(y:ys)` to a single item, we are letting `y` be the first list, and `ys` be all the rest of the lists.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks. As for the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set is what I was referencing. Specifically the "Examples" section.

Comment: So you're basically trying to work with sets, not lists. This explains the confusion everyone has had with your examples, since you specifically talk about lists, but are looking for a set-based algorithm. You can apply the same principles to come up with a similar function that works on sets, but it's not just a simple change to my answer: you'd have to rewrite it. Perhaps you should ask another question, that's more clear about what you want from an answer.

Comment: What about `["13","2"]`?

Comment: @eulerfx What about it? What are you asking that's different than the other comments on this answer that mention that same value?

Answer (score 1):

A right fold solution would be:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

separate :: Foldable t => t a -> [[[a]]]
separate = foldr (\i -> concatMap (inc i)) [[]]
    where
    inc i []     = [[[i]]]
    inc i (x:xs) = ((i:x):xs):((x:) <$> inc i xs)
```

then:

```
\> separate [1, 2]
[[[1,2]],[[2],[1]]]

\> separate [1, 2, 3]
[[[1,2,3]],[[2,3],[1]],[[1,3],[2]],[[3],[1,2]],[[3],[2],[1]]]
```