# Haskell: Recursive Function on Sets

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to write a (somewhat) basic recursive function that generates the partitions of a set. I am referencing this wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) for my definition of set partitions.

I currently have a function that produces most, but not all, of the partitions:

```
separate :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
separate [] = [[]]
separate (b:bs) = [[b]:s | s <- separate bs] ++ [(b:qs):qss | (qs:qss) <- separate bs]

>separate [1,2,3]
[[[1],[2],[3]],[[1],[2,3]],[[1,2],[3]],[[1,2,3]]]
```

As you can see it is missing the `[[1,3],[2]]` variant.

I was wondering if this function could be easily modified to accommodate my requirements, or if a whole new function would need to be created. Thanks.

Comment: answer to your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35392818/625914

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Recursive List Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388734/haskell-recursive-list-function)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with `[(b:qs):qss | (qs:qss) <- separate bs]`, you only prepend `b` to the *first* subset of each of the `bs` partitions. You want to prepend it to *every* subset.

```
separate (b:bs) = [[b]:s | s <- separate bs]
               ++ (singleModifies (b:) =<< separate bs)

-- | All possibilities of applying a function to exactly one element in the list.
singleModifies :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
singleModifies _ [] = []
singleModifies f (x:xs) = (f x:xs) : map (x:) (singleModifies f xs)
```

In case you don't understand what the [`=<<`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) operator does: it “flattens” the nesting of lists. `separate bs` already generates a list of partitions; for each of these we get another list from `singleModifies`, but in the end we're not interested in which list came from where, so we just [join](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:join) (aka [concat](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concat)) them together. Another way for writing this would be

```
separate (b:bs) = [[b]:s | s <- separate bs]
               ++ concat [singleModifies (b:) bp | bp <- separate bs]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to experiment with this function to try and really understand what is happening, but the only problem is I can't get what you provided to compile. Am I missing something here? Any ideas?

Comment: @K.Anderson no, it's just that my code didn't work yet. Fixed now.