# All possible orders of a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to teach myself Haskell and the book I'm using has said to create a list of all possible formations of said list, the example is as follows (roughly translated):

Given the list, ls = [1,2,3], there are 5 possible form in which this could occur:

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
[[1,2],[3]]
[[1,3],[2]]
[[2,3],[1]]
[[1,2,3]]
```

How would I even start about coding this?

Thank you and sorry for English, it is not my first language.

Comment: You should expect that this function will be recursive. Therefore the standard questions to ask yourself are: What is the base case? What should the function return in the base case? What is the recursive case? How can I use the result of calling this function on some smaller input in the recursive case? I encourage you to ponder these questions, then update your question to discuss the thoughts you have had, and where if anywhere you find it difficult to address these standard questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Recursive Function on Sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397857/haskell-recursive-function-on-sets)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Recursive List Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388734/haskell-recursive-list-function)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Daniel Wagner's comment:

First, explain precisely what you want. I would put it like this:

> Given a list, `xs :: [a]`, whose elements are all distinct, produce a list `yss :: [[[a]]]` representing all the ways to partition the elements of `xs` into non-empty lists.

Now, consider cases:

```
ways :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
ways [] = ?
ways (ys : yss) = ?
```

You can expect the second case to be recursive. You can also expect to need to write at least one helper function.